# Oracle - inner and left join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

```
create table t1 (v varchar2(500), n number);
Insert into T1 (V,N) values ('a',1);
Insert into T1 (V,N) values ('bb',2);
Insert into T1 (V,N) values ('c',3);
Insert into T1 (V,N) values ('d',4);

create table t2 (v varchar2(500), n number);
Insert into T2 (V,N) values ('a',1);
Insert into T2 (V,N) values ('bb',2);

select * from t1 join t2 on t1.v = t2.v 
union all
select * from t1 LEFT join t2 on t1.v = t2.v ;
```

Output:

```
    a     1     a         1
    bb    2     bb        2
    a     1     a         1
    bb    2     bb        2
    d     4     (null)  (null)
    c     3     (null)  (null)
```

Can we get the same above output from single scan of T1 and T2 ie from single query without UNION ALL etc? Want to re-write the above Select query so that it scans the tables T1 and T2 only once and give the same result. See the LEFT join.

---

The output cant be changed as we are passing it further in the application, duplicate data is required as per the requirement.

Comment: Why do you want the first two rows twice? Are you maybe looking for a `full outer join`? http://rextester.com/RMEY58806

Comment: Odd expected result.

Comment: what do u mean by load once? You meant to say use only once in the query?

Answer (score 1):

> " Want to re-write the above Select query so that it scans the tables T1 and T2 only once"

You could use subquery factoring . The WITH clauses read each table once and the UNION-ed queries read from them:

```
with cte1 as ( select * from t1 )
   , cte2 as ( select * from t2 ) 
select * from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.v = cte2.v 
union all
select * from cte1 LEFT join cte2 on cte1.v = cte2.v ;
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30c88/1).

Comment: The output cant be changed as we are passing it further in the application, duplicate data is required as per the requirement. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name and APC. With clause will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid excess joins and unions by doubling the rows:

```
select t1.*,t2.* from t1
  left join t2 on t1.v=t2.v
  cross join (select 1 as dbl from dual 
            union select 2 as dbl from dual) dbl
where dbl=1 or t2.v is not null
```